# How to get the max with a where condition in this situation Mongoose / Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working with Mongoose, I have a collection that has documents like this

```
{
"_id" : 1,
    "body" : "[{\"order_id\":\"647936\",\"order_datetime\":\"2015-12-02 11:10:00\"}]",
    "user_info" : {
        "contact_email" : "test@test.com",
        "contact_phone" : "1234567",
    },
    "type" : "ORDERS",
    "version" : 1
}

{
"_id" : 2,
    "body" : "[{\"order_id\":\"647936\",\"order_datetime\":\"2015-12-02 11:10:00\"}]",
    "user_info" : {
        "contact_email" : "test@test.com",
        "contact_phone" : "1234567",
    },
    "type" : "ORDERS",
    "version" : 2
}

{
"_id" : 3,
    "body" : "[{\"order_id\":\"647936\",\"order_datetime\":\"2015-12-02 11:10:00\"}]",
    "user_info" : {
        "contact_email" : "test@test.com",
        "contact_phone" : "1234567",
    },
    "type" : "ORDERS",
    "version" : 3
}
```

As you can see in body field you can see the order_id , so same order_id can be repeated in multiple in documents but the version will be different.

> What I want is I want to search for the maximum version number for a
>   given order_id .
>
> In my case it would be 3 .

I tried to use simple queries like

```
myCollection.aggregate([
                        { "$match" : { "body.order_id" : 647936 } },
                        { "$group": {
                            "_id" :"version",
                            "max": { "$max": "version" }
                            }}
                        ] , function(err, data){

                                console.log(err);
                                console.log(data);
                            });
```

But the result is

```
null
[]
```

** Note that my mongoose connection is working fine and I can do some simple queries and results are OK.

Comment: Looks like you have a storage problem here. It would seem that "body" here has been stored as a "string" where it seems you acutally wanted an array of structured documents. Or is your output just stringified incorrectly?

Comment: No it is  stored it as a string . This project was  started by  different person so he has used it like that .

Comment: Then that is why nothing is returned, as there is no such field `body.order_id` to match to. I would suggest correcting the data first (good way), or using a regex to match the string (bad way). Then it is a simple matter of "ordering" results by "version" and just returning the "last/first" result. i.e `limit()`. No need for aggregation here.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Thanks i have corrected the data . now trying to get the result :) . if you can help me on that it would be great , thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is the problem here since what seems to be intended as a structured document has been stored as a string:

```js
// Bad bit
"body" : "[{\"order_id\":\"647936\",\"order_datetime\":\"2015-12-02 11:10:00\"}]",
```

Instead you would want this:

```js
// Acutally data and not a string
"body" : [{ "order_id": "647936", "order_datetime": ISODate("2015-12-02 11:10:00.000Z" }],
```

With data like that, getting the latest version is a simple matter of ordering the results, without the overhead of `.aggregate()`:

```js
myCollection.find({ "body.order_id": "647936" })
    .sort({ "version": -1 }).limit(1).exec(function(err,result) {

})
```

No need to aggregate and it's much faster than doing so, as you are just picking out the document with the latest (largest) version number.

---

In order to "fix" the data you can do something like this as a "one shot" execution in the shell:

```js
var bulk = db.myCollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

// query selects just those "body" elements that are currently a string
db.myCollection.find({ "body": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    var fixBody = JSON.parse(doc.body);  // Just parse the string
    fixBody.forEach(function(el) {
        // Fix dates
        el.order_datetime = new Date(
            Date.parse(el.order_datetime.split(" ").join("T") + "Z")
        );
    });

    // And queue an update to overwrite the "body" data
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "body": fixBody }
    });
    count++;

    // Send every 1000
    if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.myCollection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    }
});

// Send any remaining batched
if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
    bulk.execute();
```

You might also want to convert those "strings" other than the date to numeric values in a similar fashion and change appropriately in the query.

Comment: Great , thank you very much :) :)  , i wrote the same query but i was missing .exec  :)